# Disable 'allow permission to send push notification' in Safari 11.1

Tags: safari, permission, notifications, apns

Even though the option of "Allow websites to ask permission to send push notifications" is *unchecked*, I get alert in websites asking for permissions. How do disable this completely?

[image: Safari Website > Notifications Pane]

Also to confirm, I'm getting the native alerts asking for permission. Like this:

[image: Example of alert asking for permission]

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in Safari, you should report in Apple, as did I